# Callback VIMEO transcoding

Tags: upload, callback, vimeo

We are implementing an integration of our application with VIMEO. However, we are having difficulty in verifying the process of converting uploaded videos. We need to store in the CMS and on mobile devices the tumbnails and video files. The VIMEO API would have a way to notify us when the conversion process was finalized? For example a callback URL.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported by the Vimeo API, but is a feature we would like to implement. We will send out an announcement when we release it!

Comment: OK. We create a cron job to verify the video's status using API. This is a alternative form to solve this problem.

Comment: I would love this feature as well. I'm also doing a cronjob to look for 0kb images, but a callback would be best.

Comment: Hey Dashron, does VIMEO implemented the callback ? Or else any webhooks available ?

Comment: Hey Kanagalingam, I'm not sure. I no longer work for Vimeo so your best bet is to reach out to their customer support