# Know when a video is finished transcoding at Vimeo

Tags: vimeo-api

This question was asked 4 years ago [Callback VIMEO transcoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586194/callback-vimeo-transcoding)

Which would cover exactly what we currently need. Is there a callback API available for Vimeo so we can do some tasks after a video has been uploaded and processed?

Thanks